# Firefox API equivalence for Browser.management.onInstalled

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-app, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am porting over a Chrome plugin to Firefox as a Webextension. I have gotten almost all the way through my rather large codebase and switched things that were incompatible, however a management.onInstalled and .onUninstalled, onEnabled and onDisabled are the last few functions I can't seem to find a Firefox equivalent for. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

These events are not currently implemented in Firefox.  If you have a compelling use case for them you can add a comment at:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1282984